# add_field is not working in my case in logstash

Tags: logstash, field, addition

> _source is "tot_rjt_file_cnt:0 @version:1 log.file.path:/home/xxx/xxx-logs/ase/load01/xxxxx.xxx.com_SORT_dis_loader_daily_rpt.log
>   log.offset:67,825 tot_rty_file_cnt:0 ecs.version:1.0.0
>   agent.version:7.2.0
>   agent.ephemeral_id:0b7a5cff-79c8-4d45-9936-9d14db9eab54
>   agent.hostname:xxxxxx.xxxxx.com agent.id:fa4e2cd0-7ad4-"

here my log file path is

> /home/xxxx/xxx-logs/ase/load01/xxxxxx.xxxx.com_SORT_dis_loader_daily_rpt.log

I want to create new filed with "ase". 
adding logstash filter :

```
filter {
     grok { match => { "message" => "%{WORD:timestamp}\s%{BASE10NUM:total_file_cnt:int}\s%{BASE10NUM:total_ld_ok_cnt:int}\s%{BASE10NUM:total_ld_time:float}\s%{BASE10NUM:sec_per_tot_file:float}\s%{BASE10NUM:sec_per_ld_file:float}\s%{BASE10NUM:tot_rty_file_cnt:int}\s%{BASE10NUM:tot_rjt_file_cnt:int}" }
        overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }
        date {
                locale => "en"
                match => [ "timestamp", "yyyyMMdd" ]
                }

        if "ase" in [log.file.path] { mutate {  add_field => { "site" => "ASE" } }
        }

}
```

could you please help to add_field name as "Site" and values are "ASE"

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the condition in the `if`:

```
if "ase" in [log.file.path] { }
```

will look if the Array `log.file.path` contains the string `ase`, which is clearly not the case (since `log.file.path` is *not* an Array).

If you want to check if a `log.file.path` contains `/ase/`, use:

```
if [log.file.path] =~ "\/ase\/" { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `log` field is a json object with nested fields.

```
{ 
  "log": { 
     "file": {
         "path": "your-filename.log"
      }
   }
}
```

The correct way to access nested fields in logstash is using squared brackets, try to change your conditional to use squared brakes in the field name.

```
if "ase" in [log][file][path] { 
    mutate {  
        add_field => { "site" => "ASE" } 
    }
}
```

`[log][file][path]` is no the same as `log.file.path`, the first is a json object, which is how the `beats` collectors store data, the second is a field with dots in its name.